# Tokenization and dtMatrix in python with nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-mining, text-analysis

I have a csv file with 2 columns — sentence and label.
I want to make a document-term matrix for these sentences. I am new in Python and so far I could reach this:

```
import nltk
import csv
import numpy
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag
reader = csv.reader(open('my_file.csv', 'rU'), delimiter= ";",quotechar = '"')
for line in reader:
for field in line:
    tokens = word_tokenize(field)
```

But I don't get how to take only one column for tokenization and create such matrix.

I have read few topics on stackoverflow regarding the same issue but in all examples I could find, csv-file contained only 1 column or they hardcoded texts.

I would really appreciate any answer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the file `example.csv` like the following:

```
label;sentence
"class1";"This is an example sentence."
"class1";"This is another example sentence."
"class2";"The third one is random."
```

**Read the file** using `DictReader` instead of `reader` so that it gives you each line as a dictionary

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('example.csv', 'r'), delimiter= ";",quotechar = '"')
lines = list(reader) # this is a list each is dictionary
sentences = [l['sentence'] for l in lines] # get only
```

**document-term matrix using scikit-learn**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer(lowercase=True) 
X_count = count_vect.fit_transform(sentences)
```

The dictionary (word to index dictionary) can be accessed using `count_vect.vocabulary_` and `X_count` is your document-term matrix,

```
X_count.toarray()
# [[1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
#  [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]]
```

**document-term matrix using nltk** this is kind of the same as scikit-learn but you can build the dictionary yourself and transform sentences to document-term matrix

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from itertools import chain, groupby
import scipy.sparse as sp

word_tokenize_matrix = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
vocab = set(chain.from_iterable(word_tokenize_matrix))
vocabulary = dict(zip(vocab, range(len(vocab)))) # dictionary of vocabulary to index

words_index = []
for r, words in enumerate(word_tokenize_matrix):
    for word in sorted(words):
        words_index.append((r, vocabulary.get(word), 1))
```

After getting row/column/value of each sentences, you can apply groupby and count words that appear more that one time.

```
rows, cols, data = [], [], []
for gid, g in groupby(words_index, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
    rows.append(gid[0])
    cols.append(gid[1])
    data.append(len(list(g)))
X_count = sp.csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)))
```

and here, you can build your own document-term matrix!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Your welcome. This code is very crude tho. Please let me know if you have further question!